# Jquery Accordion for rows in a table HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need that my table has an accordion like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ht6NM/) I tried this option but is not compatible with my version of jquery.  In the example of the page the jquery version is 1.4.4 and in my application the jquery version is 1.6.  How can I do this code compatible with my version of jquery for the next table has an accordion as I want?

```
<table width="900px" border="0px">
    <h1>My table</h1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>column 2</th>
            <th>column 3</th>
            <th>column 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="title_section" colspan="4">
                <div id="title_section">Title 1</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title_section">
                <div id="title_subsection">Title subsection 1</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item1">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>xyz1</td>
            <td>abc1</td>
            <td>ebt1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item1">
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>xyz2</td>
            <td>abc2</td>
            <td>ebt2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title_section">
                <div id="title_subsection">Servicios profesionales domiciliarios</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item1">
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>xyz3</td>
            <td>abc3</td>
            <td>ebt3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item1">
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>xyz</td>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>ebt</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="total">
            <td colspan="2">item5</td>
            <td colspan="2" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title_section" colspan="4">
                <div id="title_section">Title 2</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item2">
            <td>Item 11</td>
            <td>xyz11</td>
            <td>abc11</td>
            <td>ebt11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item2">
            <td>Item 22</td>
            <td>xyz22</td>
            <td>abc22</td>
            <td>ebt22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item2">
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>xyz33</td>
            <td>abc33</td>
            <td>ebt33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="total">
            <td colspan="2">dadkfdl</td>
            <td colspan="2" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I thank for your help.

Comment: Use any of the available accordion plugins http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-accordion-menus-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to include jquery UI, as you did in the fiddle.

jqueryui.com